@Transactional annotation is not working in springboot for multiple child classes
I am trying to keep multiple db calls in multiple classes under same transaction.
EX: Parent class (service 1)
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Processor {
  private final StudentHandler studentHandler;

  private final TeacherHandler teacherHandler;

@Transactional(rollbackFor = {CustomException.class})
public void execute(MessageObj msg) {
//calling handler one

studentHandler.process(msg);


//calling handler two

teacherHandler.process(msg);
}
}

Code of handler class 1
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudnetHandler {

private final StudnetDao studentDao;

@Transactional(rollbackFor = {CustomException.class})
public void process(MessageObj obj){

studentDao.saveStudent(obj);


}

}


Code of handler class 2
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TeacherHandler {

private final TeacherDao teacherDao;

@Transactional(rollbackFor = {CustomException.class})
public void process(MessageObj obj){

teacherDao.saveTeacher(obj);


}

}

**Student Dao class **
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class StudentDao {

private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Transactional(rollbackFor = {CustomException.class})
public void saveStudent(MessageObj obj){

jdbcTemplate.save("student_query",obj);

jdbcTemplate.save("audit_query",obj);

}

}

**Teacher Dao class **
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class TeacherDao {

private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Transactional(rollbackFor = {CustomException.class})
public void saveTeacher(MessageObj obj){

jdbcTemplate.save("student_query",obj);


}

}

In the above code, i am expecting to rollback all the queries if custom exception comes in any query (teacher,student).
When testing i can see if exception is coming in teacherhandler only teacherDao queries are getting rollback but not student queries.
Can someone please help what needs to be done if i want to rollback student queries as well if exception comes in teacherhandler?
Note:
Pls ignore syntactical mistakes. Thanks in advance.

What's your autocommit setting on your Datasource?

you have placed @trasactional on both handler class,so it will create a seperate transaction for both, so for example if exception occurs in teacherhandler then queries in teacherdao only will roll back and studenthandler trasaction will commmit successfully if it has completed without issue, to solve these(all queries will roll back if exception occur in either one), place @transaction on execute method in processor class and remove @transaction from studenthandler and teacherhandler class.so that both handler will be under single transaction.
